# Request all Revenue Cat customers with the REST API

Tags: revenuecat

I would like to query my customers (with active / trial subscriptions) from Revenue Cat.
I do see that i can get any customer by using this [endpoint](https://www.revenuecat.com/reference/subscribers).

I would like to be able to do some pagination and retrieve the customers directly without having to do 1 request per customer AND know their ID.

I am not sure that this is possible since i have not seen anything in the REST API but i prefer ask to be sure in case i have missed something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer from RevenueCat support team :

> We will likely have a general "list customers" endpoint within the next couple of months, but for more detailed searching and filtering, we do not currently have an ETA.

So it will likely be available in second half of 2023 !

Comment: Is this available already?

Comment: Not yet as far as i know, i will be notified by email if the support didn't forget about me, but i still don't see it available for now

Comment: not yet. And it sucks, since we cannot try a get using an "app_user_id" which doesn't exist. If not, the same endpoint creates that user. I've never seen that in my life: a GET endpoint which has POST and GET methods unseparated. That's not a quality aspect in an API.